# How to resize collection View cells ( likely PInterest app )

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6.1

I need to develop the uicollectionview with uneven cell sizes ( likely PInterest App format ).

Here am using some custom collectionview cell class to represent my cell image and cell name. so kindly suggest me the way to do

Answer (score 1):

`UICollection` is the way that you can create app have `pinterest` like `UI`. UICollectionView is allowed to dynamic render its size.

Here are the sample code that have `pinterst` like `UI`.

[UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

[JSPintDemo](https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo)

[WaterflowView](https://github.com/aceisScope/WaterflowView)

[NHBalancedFlowLayout](https://github.com/njdehoog/NHBalancedFlowLayout)

if you are beginner in `UICollectionView` then bellowed link will help you.

[beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Hope this help  you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload single cell, and I think you need to use this UICollectionView method

```
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;
```